# Proper way to seed data in production django

Tags: django, seeding

I have a set of tables that are basically just some definition tables for example:

```
Schedule_table
--------
1|Daily
2|Weekly
3|Monthly
```

```
Run_type_table
--------
1|Concurrent
2|Singular
3|Multi-prong
```

These are static tables, that should never be edited.  I was looking for an approach on how I can ensure these tables are "perfect". Basically when running some command, it cleans up the table to match the seed file exactly.  If I remove data from the seed file, it deletes it, if I add a definition, it adds to the database on rerun, etc..

I was looking at this - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/initial-data/ but this seems to be an approach for test data.  I am looking for something that I can use in production.

Comment: Fixtures are the right approach.  Go ahead an define your fixtures and use `loaddata` to add them to your db in production.  (_expected that this is a one time configuration event_)

Comment: @monkut I would like this to be re-runnable.  So for example, when ever I start my container it will first `loaddata` then start my django server.

Comment: You can script it to run `loaddata` when your container starts, but that doesn't sound like a production system. (if that's the case you would be continually reloading data to the production database)